# How to disable the "Usage Data Upload" message in Eclipse?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, eclipse

Using Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu 10.04.

Every once in a while, I get the "**Usage Data Upload**" dialog popping up. Clicking on "**Cancel**" closes the dialog but it pops again after a while.

I tried the "**Turn UDC feature Off**" selection followed by clicking "**Finish**", but again it pops after a while.

I then tried the same selection with "**Next>**". It goes to "**Terms of Use**" tab, and when I confirm, it gets to the "**Upload Preview**" pane.

How can I eliminate this dialog for once and for all?